# SQL Server: undo the last executed query with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any algorithm or easy way to undo last executed query in SQL Server. I am using C# and I'0ve written a program integrated with SQL Server. Think like paint. When I press "ctrl + z" it gets back last operation.

Comment: You can either use **(1)** a transaction which you can abort (rollback) if you don't like the results, or **(2)** you can restore a **backup** that you have taken before doing a risky operation.

Comment: See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Restoring a back-up seems fairly heavy-handed approach to an undo.   The answer here *is* using transactions and rolling them back.  SQL isn't an extention of C#, so your concept of undo is going to be fairly limited (especially if transactions start overlapping on recordset manipulation).   To get you started:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Comment: So, if I use transaction before every execution , I can undo the last last execution ?

Comment: by the way I have more than 1 user. Transaction locks the table.

Comment: A good practice would be to insert into SQL data that'd been verified.
So any "cancel" or "ctrl+z" should be something done locally, and after the data being verified, save it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can not.

As people have said in the comment the only way to undo changes in the past without any prepared way of undoing can only be undone by restoring a backup.

As to your comment about transactions locking tables, that is true. But any and all changes to the database are done by transactions. The only difference is implicit or explicit transactions which have the same end result.

So for all practical purposes this:

```
INSERT demo..employees (firstname,lastname)
VALUES ('Joe','Doe')
```

Does the same as this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT demo..employees (firstname,lastname)
    VALUES ('Joe','Doe')
    IF 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        PRINT 'Undo'
    END
    ELSE COMMIT
```

Except ofcourse that the second block will Always rollback. Hope this helps and have fun!

Comment: So, I failed. I am wondering about other programs. Many of them have undo attribute. How they do that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you need a database you need a database and they all behave like this. Give some more data on your problem and maybe we can help you